# Why I see this output in netstat (Local Address)

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp, ping, netstat

I have a server in a small network. This server has a hostname, let's say `hostname1.network.internal`. And the current IP adress of this server is `192.168.0.54`.

But when I call the command `netstat | head -4`, I get this output:

```
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address                Foreign Address              State
tcp        0      0 hostname239.network.inte:ssh somehost1.network.int:40178  ESTABLISHED
tcp        0     64 hostname239.network.inte:ssh somehost2.network.in:54291   ESTABLISHED
```

Why is there no `hostname1` in the column `Local Address`, but the hostname of some other machine in the network?

Also, pinging does strange things: When I start pinging `hotstname1.network.internal`, I get this message:

```
PING hostname1.network.internal (192.168.2.118) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- hostname1.network.internal ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2999ms
```

Can you give me some hints, what the source of the problem might be?

Answer (score 1):

`netstat` without the `-n` option is just resolving your IP address and gets `hostname1.network.internal`. Try `getent hosts 192.168.0.54`: if this is not the intended answer, check your `/etc/hosts` file or your DNS server.

As for the `ping` command, you can see that `hostname1.network.internal` resolves to `192.168.2.118` which is probably not on the same network. You don't tell us enough about this second address (another interface on the same server?). Again, this may be a hostname resolution issue (try `getent hosts 192.168.2.118` and `getent hosts hostname1.network.internal` and see if the results are consistent).